# Off topic question - reason?

Tags: support

This particular question was marked as off topic on Physical Fitness -https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/increasing-heartrate

I read the Helpcenter link for Physical Fitness at https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

If the problem is related to Physical Fitness like increase in Heart Rate will it not be on - topic ?

Does the question has been closed because it is asking for test/checkups ?

If yes then why those are not added?

Is there any other reason behind this ?

If it is truly off topic where should these type of question will be asked any suggesion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd assume it's because you're asking about a possible medical issue. From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> wellness, general health, **medical advice** and injuries unrelated to exercise

are listed under as off-topic subjects for questions.

Where should this kind of question be asked?

Nowhere on the StackExchange network, and likely nowhere on the internet in general. If you're concerned about it, or have questions, then you should go to a doctor. They're qualified to assess you and make a diagnosis, random people on a Q&A site or a forum aren't.

The fact that it's off-topic aside, there are other reasons to close it: it's quite low quality (very light on potentially important details) and also very localized (the reason your heartrate isn't increasing probably isn't going to be much use to anybody else).

Comment: +1 for an answer but one question what will happen if OP would have asked for a exercise for maintaining his heart rate will it have been on topic then ?

Comment: I can't really say, it would depend on the circumstances. What's his overall health situation, does he have a history of medical problems or not, can he exercise (sub)maximally on other days, etc

Comment: @IvoFlipse ok thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2):

With the current information available in that question, it is being viewed as a medical question. The help page states that this site is **not** about:

> wellness, general health, medical advice and injuries unrelated to exercise

It may well  be that there's a benign physiological reason for why the OP can't increase his heart rate, such as overtraining or fatigue. However, since that's not clear we can only assume medical reasons in which case we should refer the OP to his doctor

Comment: +1 ok thanks for an answer i was just not able to find out the exact reason